# What is the binary STR_FILE_SYS_BIND_DATA_WIN7_FORMAT PIDL format?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-shell, shell-extensions

The [bind context strings documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/str-constants#STR_FILE_SYS_BIND_DATA_WIN7_FORMAT) says that `STR_FILE_SYS_BIND_DATA_WIN7_FORMAT` determines if you get the Windows 7 or 8.1 PIDL format but where is the documentation for these PIDL formats?

How would callers of `IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName` know if they should pass this "flag"?

And as a implementer of a namespace extension, should I even care about this "flag"?

And as a change notification listener, how does this "flag" affect `SHChangeNotify` and friends? When `SHChangeNotify` is called with a path string, it creates a [simple PIDL](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130503-00/?p=4463). Is this always the same format or does it depend on the Windows version?

PIDLs are supposed to be [persistable and transportable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144093(v=vs.85).aspx#PIDL) so what happens if you pass a Windows 8.1 PIDL to the default filesystem IShellFolder implementation on Windows 7 and older?

Comment: If I had $1 for every time I've screamed in anguish "but where is the documentation for this" I'd be able to buy Microsoft.

Comment: pidl created with this flag bit different compare without it. your extension of course can ignore this flag. i not think that this affect something at all. simply ms deside bit change internal idl format for filesystem items

Comment: olld format is `IDFOLDER`. format with this flag internal called `IDFOLDEREX_V3` (the `CFSFolder::_PopulateIDXV3` build it) view also `IDFOLDEREX_V4`, used in `_PopulateIDXLatest`. not think that this visible affect something. very deep internal